# Updating custom model manager doesn't take effect

Tags: django, django-models

I have an `Order` model with a custom model manager called `OrderManager` as follows.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # Model fields are declared here.
    ... 
    objects = OrderManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()

class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(OrderManager, self).get_queryset().filter(Q(x='y') | Q(x='y'))
```

I updated `OrderManager` class by adding another filter to the queryset, and the new implementation turned out to be

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(OrderManager, self).get_queryset().filter(~Q(order_status='Cancelled'), Q(x='y') | Q(x='y'))
```

However, when I retrieve data from the `Order` model using the updated manager, it ignores the changes and still brings the objects whose `order_status` is 'Cancelled'.

```
orders = Order.objects.all() # Retrieves cancelled orders as well.
```

On the other hand, applying the last additional filter explicitly works:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(~Q(order_status='Cancelled') # Ignores the cancelled orders.
```

Is it a migration issue or what? I feel like there is a silly mistake I'm making somewhere (probably not related to this code) but I just got blind. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

ps: I'm using Django 1.5.5 on Webfaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before django 1.6 method was named [`get_query_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets), not [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) (check additional underscore).

So in django 1.5 and earlier it is needed to override `get_query_set` method:

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(OrderManager, self).get_query_set().filter(~Q(order_status='Cancelled'), Q(x='y') | Q(x='y'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I'll give it a try as soon as I go back to my workstation and mark your answer as accepted.